# Select a few columns using NamedParameterJDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm using NamedParameterJDBCTemplate in Spring and trying to select only few columns instead of all columns. But I am facing an error - org.SpringFramework.BadSqlGrammarException.

My DAO Class has the following code.

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt;

... // Some other code

String query = "SELECT t.name AS NAME, t.city AS CITY FROM t WHERE t.country = :countryName";
MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
param.addValue("countryName", "GERMANY");
List<Person> pl = npjt.query(sql,param, new PersonMapper()); // Throws org.SpringFramework.BadSqlGrammarException
```

The Person Model Class is as follows.

```
public class Person {
String name;
String city;
String country;
String address;

// All getters & setters
}
```

The Mapper Class is as follows.

```
public class PersonMapper implements RowMapper {

public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
    p.setCity(rs.getString("CITY"));
    return p;
  }

}
```

Facing the error only if select a few columns. When doing a select *, things are working fine.

Comment: could you also add to the question the output of the command : `for (int i =1 ; i<= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){System.out.println(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));}` ? It may be of help to you to identify the names of the columns that you are dealing with. Also the stacktrace of the `BadSqlGrammarException` may be of help.

Comment: @marius_neo - The debug pointer doesn't get inside the mapRow function. It breaks in here, npjt.query(...) where the sql call is made.

Comment: Is the table name from the example code that you posted really `t` or is the table name really missing from your query?

Comment: It is 't' only. Tried after renaming but ended up in the same error.

Comment: I'd use a `try/catch(BadSqlGrammarException e)` block and print out `e.getSql()` . Also go step by step to find the issue - use first a generic query `SELECT name, city  FROM t` and then add your named parameter and then rename the columns and see where the bad sql grammar exception occurs.

Comment: [Steve Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2670689/steve-jobs) did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @Avinesh can you try removing all the "t." from the query and try it. If "t" is your table, you don't actually have an alias to your table name.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks bad.
Try with

```
String query = "SELECT t.name AS NAME, t.city AS CITY FROM Person t WHERE t.country =        :countryName";
```

Assuming that your table/class name is 'Person'. 
Otherwise replace 'Person' with the good table name

Comment: The table name is not the one creating the problem. But anyways good suggestion.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?